# "k" key sends focus in event

Tags: debian, xorg, keyboard

After a dist-upgrade to wheezy, my "k"-Key misbehaves. When typed in a gnome-terminal, no "k" is printed. Instead the terminal seems to grab the focus and will not release it. If I drag-down  the mouse *outside* the terminal it highlights line *inside* the terminal. Also regular mouse clicks no longer work.

I ran `xev` an it shows three events when pressing "k"

- a FocusIn event
- a FocusOut event
- a KeymapNotify event

This only happens when I log in through a display manager using my account. It happens with gdm3 and wdm (I have not tested any others)

When I log in as a different user, the "k" key works.

When I log in through a display managaer using a "failsafe" session it also works. Other than that the issue occurs with many different session types.

When startig X from the commandline all is fine. The issue only occurs when logging in through a display manager.

AFAICS all other key work, including the uppercase shift-K

I looked for "dpkg-dist" files in /etc/X11 and only found the following:

```
./XftConfig.dpkg-dist
./rstart/config.dpkg-dist
```

So it appears to be related to something attached to my user account. In my dispair I renamed the ~/.config directory, but that didn't resolve the issue.

I am aware of [`p` key doesn't work in X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/p-key-doesnt-work-in-x), and I believe it is the same issue, but I have no idea, where I could possibly have remapped the key or how to track this down.

Comment: What window manager or desktop environment do you use? Does this still happen if you use a different one? Do you have a `~/.Xmodmap` or otherwise run `xmodmap` when you log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the answer:

In my case the display-managers start xbinkeys. When starting X from the commandline xbindkeys was (of course) not started. For some reason my .xbindkeysrc bound the letter "k".

The problem disappeared when I killed xbindkeys (which is not a permanent solution) or after I stripped down .xbindkeysrc.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was due to the leftover ibus config files from the previous version of Ubuntu. I removed them (located in ~/.config/ibus) and issued the following command to recreate the configs, and then logged out and logged in.

```
ibus reset-config
```